# java - compareTo method

Tags: java, sorting, comparable, compareto

i have a question about compareTo method in java. So this compareTo method compares CarOwner objects and if the calling object is earlier in chronological time in comparison to the argument returns -1, if the calling object is later in chronological time in comparison to the argument returns 1, if the calling object and argument are the same in chronological time returns 0. if the argument passed in is not a CarOwner object (use instanceof or getClass to determine this) or is null, returns -1.

and i came up with this code, but it doesnt seem like its working, anybody have any suggestion?

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    if ((o != null ) && (o instanceof CarOwner))
    {
        CarOwner otherOwner = (CarOwner) o;
        if (otherOwner.compareTo(getYear()) > 0)
            return -1;
        else if (otherOwner.compareTo(getYear()) < 0)
            return 1;
        else if (otherOwner.equals(getYear()))
            if (otherOwner.compareTo(getMonth()) > 0)
                return -1;
            else if (otherOwner.compareTo(getMonth()) < 0)
                return 1;
            else if (otherOwner.equals(getMonth()))
                return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: First, I suggest using generics. Change your class decluration to `public class CarOwner implements Comparable<CarOwner> `. Then you will have to change your `compareTo` method to `public int compareTo(CarOwner otherOwner)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work, if getYear() and getMonth() returns the comparable objects

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    if ((o != null ) && (o instanceof CarOwner))
    {
        CarOwner otherOwner = (CarOwner) o;
        int result = otherOwner.getYear().compareTo(getYear());
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        return otherOwner.getMonth().compareTo(getMonth());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

if getYear() and getMonth() returns int, then:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    if ((o != null ) && (o instanceof CarOwner))
    {
        CarOwner otherOwner = (CarOwner) o;
        if (otherOwner.getYear() > getYear())
            return -1
         else if (otherOwner.getYear() < getYear())
             return 1
         else if  (otherOwner.getMonth() > getMonth())
             return -1
         else if  (otherOwner.getMonth() < getMonth())
             return 1;
         else 
             return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I tried to compile this but it says int cannot be deferenced

Comment: Is this function is a part of CarOwner class?

Comment: If getYear() and getMonth() return int, use `Integer.compare()`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing properties of this instance to the entire otherOwner instance. You should  compare to properies of otherOwner.

For example

`otherOwner.getYear().compareTo(getYear())`

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the method to some CarOwner, what will happen is:

1. Yes, it is an instance of CarOwner. We go into your if block.
2. but when you call otherOwner.compareTo, you are passing "Year" or "Month", which I assume it is an integer or string.
3. You then goes to compareTo method of otherOwner, your "Year" or "Month" is not an instance of CarOwner, then it always returns -1.

So what you should do is compare "Year" or "Month" with otherOwner's "Year" or "Month" and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

As you are comparing different fields and digging deeper if year field is the same, I suggest the following

```
int oy=otherOwner.getYear();
int ty=this.getYear();
int om=otherOwner.getMonth();
int tm=this.getMonth();

if(oy==ty){
    return om-tm;
}else{
    return oy-ty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the **Compareable** interface on your class (`Comparable<CarOwner>`) after that use CarOwner for your compareTo method instead of Object (`int compareTo(CarOwner otherOwner)`)